# EFCore: Attach as Unchanged multiple times

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a deep hierarchical entity, which contains an array of a second entity, each of which reference an associated third entity. I am struggling to get this model to save to the database, as EFCore is complaining about the third entity being Attached multiple times.

For example:

```cs
public class Foo {
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

  public static void RunFluent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>();
     entity.HasKey(p => p.FooId);
     entity.HasMany(f => f.Bars).WithOne(b => b.Foo);
  }
}

public class Bar {
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
  public virtual Baz Baz { get; set; }


  public static void RunFluent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     EntityTypeBuilder<Bar> entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>();
     entity.HasKey(b => b.BarId);
     entity.HasOne(b => b.Foo).WithMany(f => f.Bars);
     entity.HasOne(b => b.Baz).WithMany(b => b.Bars);
  }
}

public class Baz {
  public int BazId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

  public static void RunFluent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     EntityTypeBuilder<Baz> entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Baz>();
     entity.HasKey(b => b.BazId);
     entity.HasMany(b => b.Bars).WithOne(b => b.Baz);
  }
}
```

For the FooController, my post endpoint would be something akin to:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult<Foo>> PostFoo(Foo foo)
{
  _context.Foos.Attach(foo);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtAction("GetFoo", new { id = foo.FooId }, foo);
}
```

My understanding of `DbContext.Attach(entity)` is that for all the entities reachable from the one specified, (presuming the entity has an auto-generated primary key), if the entity does *not* have a key defined, it will be tracked as **Add**; however, if it *does* have a key, it will be tracked as **Unchanged**.

My issue arrives when I add the following Foo (Baz with id == 1 already exists in the database):

```json
{
  "name": "top foo",
  "bars": [{
    "name": "bar abc",
    "baz": {
      "bazId": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "bar def",
    "baz": {
      "bazId": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "bar ghi",
    "baz": {
      "bazId": 1
    }
  }]
}
```

Per my understanding, since the Foo and the Bars don't have keys, they should be tracked as Added, and the Baz as Unchanged. However, the issue is that the Baz is being tracked multiple times, and returing the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Baz' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'BazId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I get that Attach is finding the same entity multiple times, and thus trying to track it each time, and yet as it's the same entity it throws the System.InvalidOperationException.

Why does Attach even care that it *is* tracked multiple times in this case? Since as the entity has a defined key it is tracked as Unchanged: once it sees the first, shouldn't it maintain the other instances as identical to the first?

Is there a way to tell .Attach() if you see the same entity as Unchanged, don't track subsequent ones?

Comment: Why aren't you using `.Add()` instead of `.Attach()`?

Comment: _a way to tell .Attach() if you see the same entity as Unchanged, don't track subsequent ones_. See `ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-trackgraph-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Maybe you can declare the context as scoped.

Comment: `.Add()` would give me a very different error here. Add marks everything reachable tracked as Add, and thus I would get a Primary Key conflict error.

Comment: context is definitely already scoped

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment regarding `ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` I've come up with the following, which seems to work in all cases:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(foo, e =>
{
  if (!e.Entry.IsKeySet)
  {
     e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
  }
  else
  {
     e.Entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
  }
});
```

I.e., If you don't see a key, mark it as Add, but if you do, *don't track the entity*.

This still tracks the association, but doesn't try to do anything with the associated entities, meaning they can appear as many times as necessary in the payload without causing errors.

You can add whatever other details you like, and the entities won't change; however, if the Post controller returns the entity to the front end, the inner entities returned will be what was submitted. Thus the front might see the entities as the new values on posting, which might be something to keep in mind.

Also, I have noticed that if there is Validation on an entity, particularly Required decorators—even if the inner entities have an ID, and thus will remain untracked—the validators will insist the required fields be present.

I haven't come across any issues with this yet, but am unsure if there are any potential pitfalls with this approach I haven't thought of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solve a similar problem Following your idea BM-,Just to improve a bit, by default the entry state is detached, you can skip the else, and do something like this:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(foo, e =>
{
  if (!e.Entry.IsKeySet)
  {
     e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
  }
});
```